# how to delete specific variables in R

Tags: r

I have this kind of data and I want to delete all the variables in AriT if check column says 'FALSE'

```
AriT  DST   check
1516   1450 FALSE
1150   1518 TRUE
1502   1519 TRUE
1343   1210 FALSE
```

Here is code I've got so far. some how I can't delete the variables.

```
subset(outpatient_data$AriT, outpatient_data$check != "TRUE")
```

Do I need to assign them as NULL? Thanks

Comment: Most likely explanation is that FALSE/TRUE are logical, not character variables. Try `subset(outpatient_data, outpatient_data$check == TRUE)` if you want to *keep* TRUE (your stated aim and example code don't really agree).

Comment: you can go the `tidyverse` way and try `dt %>% filter(!check == "FALSE")` to get rid of the specified rows .... assuming the values in`check` column are strings

Comment: basically I want to delete variables in AriT with check column is FALSE but I can't drop the variables by using subset query so I am asking how I can drop that variables(1516,1343 etc)

Comment: `subset(outpatient_data, check)` will do, if `check` is already logical you don't need an explicit truth test.

Comment: @neilfws Better than `check == TRUE` would be `isTRUE(check)` or nothing at all. `check` by itself already is logical.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
library(dplyr)
outpatient_data %>% 
  filter(check == TRUE)
```

output is

```
  AriT  DST check
1 1150 1518  TRUE
2 1502 1519  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are three ways of doing what you need.

The first two use base R only and give exactly the same results.

```
result1 <- subset(outpatient_data, check)
result2 <- outpatient_data[outpatient_data$check, ]
identical(result1, result2)
#[1] TRUE
```

The third uses external package `dplyr`, is equivalent to the answer by @Stephan but without the explicit test `check == TRUE`.

```
library(dplyr)

result3 <- outpatient_data %>% filter(check)
identical(result1, result3)
#[1] FALSE
```

So what is going on?
The answer is in the results' **row.names**. The base R solutions keep the original row names, `2`and `3`, the rwos selected. `dplyr` renames starting at `1`.

```
result1
#  AriT  DST check
#2 1150 1518  TRUE
#3 1502 1519  TRUE

result3
#  AriT  DST check
#1 1150 1518  TRUE
#2 1502 1519  TRUE
```

To give a dataframe row names starting at `1` just set them to `NULL`.

```
row.names(result1) <- NULL
row.names(result2) <- NULL
identical(result1, result3)
#[1] TRUE
```